# Call javascript right after the form elements are rendered

Tags: 7, nodes, javascript

I have a content-type "Document". I have a multiple select dropdown box in my form.

```
$form['priorities']['selectoffid'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Select Signatories',
    '#id' => 'select-chosen',
    '#attributes' => array('multiple' => 'multiple', 'style' => 'width:100%'),
);
```

Each option of the dropdown corresponds to a textfield. Selected option's corresponding text field are shown and unselected option's corresponding text field are hidden.

[image]

Now everytime I hit the Save button  and some other required form elements are not filled, it reloads and display the form errors. After reloading some text fields that are supposed to be visible is now hidden.

[image]

The value of the multiple select dropdown still consist of 3 values, according to the `$form_state` variable , but some of it's corresponding text fields are not visible anymore. How will I make it visible again? I tried using `after_build` form.

```
$form['#after_build'][] = 'document_monitoring_form_after_build';   

function document_monitoring_form_after_build($form, &$form_state){  

    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module','document_monitoring') . '/myscript.js');

    return $form;       
}
```

In my myscript.js :

```
alert('Javascript is called');
document.getElmentById('priority-6').style.display = 'block';
document.getElmentById('priority-22').style.display = 'block';
document.getElmentById('priority-5').style.display = 'block';
alert('Javascript is called');
```

The javascript is called before the multiple select dropdown is rendered. How will I make the javascript be called right after the form elements is rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the DOM to be ready (i.e. when then browser has finished comprehending the HTML).

Drupal's javascript API provides a natural place for your code, in the form of a [behavior](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/managing-javascript-in-drupal-7#behaviors), e.g.

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.mymoduleFoo = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      $('#priority-6').show();
      // ...
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

The `attach` method is invoked when the DOM is ready, and also at other points in the page execution when something might have changed (e.g. when an AJAX call is made), to give you the opportunity to respond to any new/change elements that might affect your code's functionality.

Comment: Thank you, tried what you said in my javascript, but it seems '#after_build' is not the right event to trigger the javascript? Am I right?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought it would make a difference, but best practice would probably be to use [`#attached`](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/managing-javascript-in-drupal-7#attached) in the form builder or form alter function itself

Comment: #attached works together with the behaviors. Thanks.